# Laravel - make json - add to variable new objects

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have this function to get all max-offers from maxoffers table:

```
public function maxoffers($id)
    {

        $offers = Maxoffer::where('article_id', $id)->latest()->get(['id', 'price', 'start', 'user_id']);

        return $offers;
    }
```

and I get this:

```
[{"id":121,"price":67,"start":"Sat, 23 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":114,"price":45,"start":"Sun, 08 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":9},{"id":113,"price":53,"start":"Sun, 24 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":111,"price":55,"start":"Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"id":110,"price":53,"start":"Fri, 03 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":107,"price":53,"start":"Wed, 03 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":106,"price":53,"start":"Mon, 01 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":105,"price":53,"start":"Tue, 16 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":104,"price":55,"start":"Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"id":101,"price":57,"start":"Wed, 17 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8}]
```

Now i have alse:
$start = 'Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00';
$end = 'Sat, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:00';

How I can go day by day throuth $offers from $start date to $end date and if there is no date for that day to add into $offers new object with data:

```
{"title":,"price":100,"start":"DATE_WHICH_NOT_EXCIST INTO_OFFERS","user_id":8}
```

So how I can go throuth $offers and if there is not some date in period from $start to $end then to add new object to json?

Comment: You can make while loop and in each turn add one day on start date, something like **$start->addDay();** . You need to make Carbon date, because this is a Carbon function.

Comment: please show me examle as a answer

Comment: Something like: 
`
$cond=true; 
$dateToCheck=something;
$start=Carbon::now(); //make your start date here 
while($cond){ 

if($dateToCheck==$date){
    //found date
    $cond=false;
}

$start->addDay();

 } 
`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't performed the following code yet but what you wanted would look like this.

Try this:

```
 public function maxoffers($id)
    {

        $start_date = ;
        $end_date = ;

        $offers = Maxoffer::where('article_id', $id)
                            ->where('start', '>=', $start_date)
                            ->where('start', '<=', $end_date)
                            ->get(['id', 'price', 'start', 'user_id']);

        $start_date = 'Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00';

        $end_date = 'Sat, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:00';

        while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

            $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));

            $count = 0;

            foreach($offers as $offer) {
                if(strtotime($offer->start) == strtotime($start_date)) {
                    $count++;
                }
            }

            if($count == 0) {
                Maxoffer::create(['title' => null, 'price' => '100', 'start' => $start_date, 'user_id' => 8 ]);   
            }

        }

        // do some code to update $offers variable before you return it

        return $offers;
    }
```

Comment: hm, no: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing